# Get random gradient background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

I am trying to get a random gradient from colorArr. I have this code:

```
    const colorArr = [
  "#e5e2ff",
  "#ffd3e1",
  "#c7f7dc",
  "#fdfdbd",
  "#ff8787",
];

const getRandomColor = () => {
  return colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];
};
```

and it perfectly picks random plain color.

When I use something like this:

```
const colorArr = [
  "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
  "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
  "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
  "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
  "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
];
```

It gives me white backgrounds instead of the actual gradients.

Comment: How are you using that code, particularly the result of `getRandomColor`?

Comment: Sam already answered thank you, it is for a card background on a react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `background-image` to use `linear-gradient` instead of `backgroundColor`

try the following code.

```js
    const colorArr = [
        "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
        "linear-gradient(-225deg, #7de2fc 0%, #b9b6e5 100%)",
    ];

    const getRandomColor = () => {
        return colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArr.length)];
    };


    const div = document.querySelector("div");
    div.style.backgroundImage = getRandomColor();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfectly working, thank you so much!